# Android- Simple bookmarks from a webview

Tags: android, webview, bookmarks, notepad

I am trying to implement a bookmark system into my app which uses webview to load one of several html pages from a spinner.  Ideally, I would like the currently viewed webpage in the webview to be saved into a bookmark database after the user clicks a button in the menu.

I know that I need a database and through other questions and answers on stackoverflow saw that Google has a tutorial that shows how this could be done.

I tried to adapt the [Notepad Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html) from Google, I was unable to implement this successfully.  Converting between Strings and Uris just didn't seem to go through correctly.  Has anyone encountered a way to make a simple bookmark system for webviews?  Or any tips on successfully using the [Notepad Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Android webview has a bookmark system
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser/+/refs/heads/master